# How to show uitableview on uibutton?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to show uitableview on button's touchupinside like below attached image without using UISplitViewController.Can anybody help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That image is showing a `UIPopoverController` that has a UITableView embedded into it.  The button itself does not have a table.

Answer (score 0):

UIPopOverController is your friend.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html